# woocommerce - hide payment method in new order email

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using woocommerce 2.6.4 and I am trying to customize the email customer gets as confirmation for new order. I need to hide Subtotal and Payment method from the order details within the email template. I manged to hide subtotal with the following code I put in functions.php:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals' );

function adjust_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $totals ) {
  unset($totals['cart_subtotal']  );
  return $totals;
}
 ?>
```

Is there any way to hide the payment method as well?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manged to figure this one out. For anyone having the same problem maybe, here is the solution. Just add

```
 unset( $totals['payment_method'] );
```

before

```
return $totals;
```